# Divisibility Proof $8^n\mid(4n)!$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction, divisibility, factorial

Is the following proposition true or false? Justify your conclusion.

For each non-negative integer $n$, $8^n\mid(4n)!$.

Attempt:

I've tried to expand $(4(n+1))!$ to show that it's equivalent to $(4n+4)(4n+3)(4n+2)(4n+1)(4n)!$ and then I tried factoring these all, to try and show that they were all divisible by $8$. But I got lost because it seemed like I did it wrong, mainly because the $8^n$ was still there and unaccounted for.

I tried to prove that the claim $P(n)$ was true for $P(0), P(1), P(2)$, and $P(3)$.

Comment: what have you tried?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this question?  Is there a point where you are getting stuck?  Have you tried some small non-negative integers to see what happens?

Comment: I've tried to expand (4n)! to show that it's equivalent to (4n+4)(4n+3)(4n+2)(4n+1)(4n)! and then I tried factoring these all, to try and show that they were all divisible by 8. But I got lost because it seemed like I did it wrong, mainly because the 8^n was still there and unaccounted for. @abiessu

Comment: I tried to prove that the claim P(n) was true for P(0), P(1), P(2), and P(3).

Comment: For each consecutive $4$ numbers as you have listed, you only need one factor of $8$ across them; $4n+2,4n+4$ combine to give this factor.  So you could start with $n=1$ and demonstrate the proposition, then use induction to finish.

Comment: always include your attempt directly in your post rather than in the comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check that it holds for $n=1$.

Try mathematical induction suppose $$8^n|(4n)!$$

We can write $(4n)!=8^nm$, where $m\in \mathbb{Z}$.

We want to prove that $$8^{n+1}|(4n+4)!$$

\begin{align}
(4n+4)! &= (4n)![(4n+4)(4n+3)(4n+2)(4n+1) ]\\
&= (8^n m)[\color{blue}4 (n+1)(4n+3)(\color{blue}2)(2n+1)(4n+1)]
\end{align}

Can you continue from here?

Comment: I'm confused as to why you were able to multiply (8^nm) to the expression that's equivalent to (4n+4)!

Comment: We have $(4n)!=8^m$ by induction hypothesis right?

Comment: We have (4(n+1))!=8^(n+1)(m) as the induction hypothesis

Comment: Our induction statement is $P(n): 8^n | (4n)!$. So given $P(n)$, we are trying to prove $P(n+1)$, that we we want to prove $8^{n+1}|(4(n+1))!$

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I just assumed by the definition of divisibility though that we would say that (4(n+1))!=8^(n+1)(m)

Comment: typing tips, surround maths object with dollar signs, also we can use curly braces after ^ to write exponent. u can click on your post and see how edit was done for a reference.

Comment: I see what you're doing here in the last step, I'm just confused because where did the $(4n+1)$ from the previous equation go? I see that you substituted $(8^{n}(m)$ for $(4n)!$ and the bolded 4 and 2 are meant to represent the 8 that would be $(8^{n}(8)$. @SiongThyeGoh

Comment: oops, that was a careless mistake, $4n+1$ should be there. yup, that's where the addtional $8$ comes from.

Comment: okay that definitely makes sense now, thank you for all your help :) @SiongThyeGoh